# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, typeerror

I have this code and it raise an error in python 3 and such a comparison can work on python 2
how can I change it?

```
import tensorflow as tf 
def train_set():
    class MyCallBacks(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs={}):
            if(logs.get('acc')>0.95):
                print('the training will stop !')
                self.model.stop_training=True
    callbacks=MyCallBacks()
    mnist_dataset=tf.keras.datasets.mnist 
    (x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=mnist_dataset.load_data()
    x_train=x_train/255.0
    x_test=x_test/255.0
    classifier=tf.keras.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
                                    ])
    classifier.compile(
                        optimizer='sgd',
                        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                        metrics=['accuracy']
                       )    
    history=classifier.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=20,callbacks=[callbacks])
    return history.epoch,history.history['acc'][-1]
train_set()
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What do you understand from that message?

Answer (score 23):

## Tensorflow 2.0

```
DESIRED_ACCURACY = 0.979

class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epochs, logs={}) :
        if(logs.get('acc') is not None and logs.get('acc') >= DESIRED_ACCURACY) :
            print('\nReached 99.9% accuracy so cancelling training!')
            self.model.stop_training = True

callbacks = myCallback()
```

Answer (score 17):

it seems that your error is similar to [Exception with Callback in Keras - Tensorflow 2.0 - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423505/exception-with-callback-in-keras-tensorflow-2-0-python)
try replacing  `logs.get('acc')` with `logs.get('accuracy')`

Answer (score 14):

It works in Python2 because in Python2 you can compare `None` with `float` but this is not possible in Python3.

This line

```
logs.get('acc')
```

returns `None` and there is your problem.

Quick solution would be to replace the condition with

```
if logs.get('acc') is not None and logs.get('acc') > 0.95:
```

If `logs.get('acc')` is `None` then the above condition will be short-circuited and the second part, `logs.get('acc') > 0.95`, will not be evaluated, therefore it will not cause the mentioned error.

Comment: I knew there's got to be someone who a: reads the question and b: writes an actual explanation on why it worked in Python 2, but not in 3, and what the general solution is. It's a nice addition of the other's to include help on why there is "none" returned in the first place, but it's not the question asked.

Answer (score 6):

Use 'acc' instead of 'accuracy' and you don't need to change.

Comment: This exact answer has already been added to this question. What does your answer add?

Answer (score 5):

Inside your callback try this :

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
      def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        print("---",logs,"---")
        '''
        if(logs.get('acc')>=0.99):
          print("Reached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
        '''
```

It gave me this
**`--- {'loss': 0.18487292938232422, 'acc': 0.94411665} ---`**

I had `acc` so I used, if had `accuracy` I would have used `accuracy`. So log and what do you have then use that.

TF goes through major changes all the time, so its ok to play safe, very safe.

Answer (score 1):

we are in the same boat from Coursera Course

So, this is my code

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: train_mnist
def train_mnist():
    # Please write your code only where you are indicated.
    # please do not remove # model fitting inline comments.

    # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if (logs.get('acc') > 0.99):
                print("\n Reached 99% Accuracy!")
                self.model.stop_training = True

    # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE

    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(path=path)
    # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
    x_train = x_train/255.0
    x_test = x_test/255.0
    
    callbacks = myCallback()

    # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, 'softmax')
    
        # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # model fitting
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[callbacks]# YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
              # YOUR CODE SHOULD END HERE
    )
    # model fitting
    return history.epoch, history.history['acc'][-1]
```

Hope, it helps you! Keep Learning

Answer (score 0):

Try using try-except

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs = {}):
    try:
      if(logs.get('acc')>0.95):
        print("\nReached")
        self.model.stop_training = True
    except:
      if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.95):
        print("Reached!!!")
        self.model.stop_training = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your line to see what the accuracy is being stored as in the first place, then you can look it up correctly when you need to compare on epoch end.

```
return history.epoch, history.history['acc'][-1]
```

here it's referenced as 'acc' but as others have noted it might be 'accuracy'

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `accuracy` use `acc` instead in this particular case since `logs.get()` is not working on `accuracy` but normally both works for common callback blocks in `TF`. If someone is looking for this issue while doing the Coursera course, this is the simplest answer to get around this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and instead of using 'acc', I changed it to 'accuracy' everywhere. So it seems that maybe it is better to try changing 'acc' to 'accuracy'.